# Cart Page is not working correctly in dreamhost webserver

Tags: php, wordpress

When we click on add cart in woocommerce site, the cart page is updated first. 
In cart page, when I click on remove on item, It's not working.

https://gobergorgohome.com/

Could you help me what it's the problem ?
The website is only wordpress and woocommercerce, backery builder etc.

Comment: Thats what you get when you miss use a Blog application as Webshop

Comment: I think that it's cache issues. but I am not sure. Local is working correctly. only server is not working.

Comment: Is it a problem between http and https.?

Comment: WC->Cart is not working correctly. It's not updated now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check ?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments

When you debug on /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/cart-fragments.min.js

```
var e = {
    url: wc_cart_fragments_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace("%%endpoint%%", "get_refreshed_fragments"),
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        time: (new Date).getTime()
    },
    timeout: wc_cart_fragments_params.request_timeout,
    success: function(e) {
        e && e.fragments && (r.each(e.fragments, function(e, t) {
            r(e).replaceWith(t)
        }),
        t && (sessionStorage.setItem(wc_cart_fragments_params.fragment_name, JSON.stringify(e.fragments)),
        s(e.cart_hash),
        e.cart_hash && a()),
        r(document.body).trigger("wc_fragments_refreshed"))
    },
    error: function() {
        r(document.body).trigger("wc_fragments_ajax_error")
    }
};
```

It returns as error.